# JS rotate animation change speed

Tags: javascript, css, anime.js

I try to make a rotationg block, which rotation speed is controlled by `<input type="range"`. The problem is that I can't find solution that **doesn't restart animation** when speed updates.

I tried three variants:

- Directly set CSS animation speed by JS. — restarts animation;
- jQuery's `animate` — doesn't work with transforms;
- Library `anime.js` — it has method for speed changing but it also
  restarts animation (or just makes block jump, it's unclear)

What method allows to create smoothly changing by JS animation?

```js
let block = anime({
   targets: '#transforms .block',
   rotateY: '360',
   easing: 'linear',
   loop: true,
   duration: 1000,
});


var el = document.querySelectorAll('#range')[0];

el.addEventListener('change', function() {  
  // console.log(value);
  // console.log(pos);
  var value = this.value;
  anime.speed = value/20;
  // console.log(block);
})
```

```css
.block {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.js"></script>
<div id="transforms">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>

<input id="range" type="range" min="0" max="20" step="1" value="10">
```

anime.js example code [On Codepen](https://codepen.io/mankutila/pen/YLqQYv)

Comment: I'm trying to do the same. I got pretty close with Velocity.js by issuing the animate command multiple times with a loop. The only problem is that there's a delay between changing the speed and it actually taking effect. The animation is consistent at least, probably because it's only adjusting the speed after a complete 360 deg rotation. 

`Velocity(rotor, { rotateZ: 360, }, {duration: 5000, loop: true, easing: "linear"});`
`Velocity(rotor, { rotateZ: 360, }, {duration: 1000, loop: true, easing: "linear"});`

Answer (score 0):

With velocity-animate library you can do a trick this way:

```
Velocity.animate(this.yourElement, {
  rotateZ: `${angle}deg`,
  duration: yourSpeed
```

})

Comment: Should I put it to `change` callback? Where to take `angle`? And why should I put it as a variable?

Comment: angle is needed for rotate direction and distance (how many degrees your element should rotate for). You don't need to put is as variable. I wrote it this way only for example

Comment: I don't think Velocity "value functions" get updated a loop is started. From the docs:
`Property values can be passed functions. These functions are called once per element — immediately before the element begins animating. Therefore, when looping/reversing, the functions are not repeatedly re-called. `

http://velocityjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

I guess triggering the speed change at the end of the animation cycle is what you need. However with this package i was unable to attach a [transitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) event listener to any of the two divs. It won't trigger. So digging into this library i suppose you may achieve a similar task by attaching a `run` property to the `anime` options object which takes a function as value and invokes it multiple times by passing a progress argument. Once this progress argument is 100 we can make our speed change operation if the speed has changed (`newSpeed !== void 0`).

Don' let `void 0` confuse you. It's just a perfect `undefined` value which i prefer to use when comparing undefined values.

```js
let block = anime({
   targets : '#transforms .block',
   rotateY : '360',
   easing  : 'linear',
   loop    : true,
   duration: 1000,
   run     : anim => anim.progress === 100 && newSpeed !== void 0 && (anime.speed = newSpeed, newSpeed = void 0)
});

var range    = document.getElementById('range'),
    newSpeed = void 0;  // perfect undefined

anime.speed = range.value/20;
range.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
                                   newSpeed = e.target.value/20;
                                 });
```

```css
.block {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.js"></script>
<div id="transforms">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>

<input id="range" type="range" min="0" max="20" step="1" value="10">
```